# IBM Worklight- Push Notifications to only Subscribed users

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to know in worklight how can we send Push Notifications to only Subscribed User?

Please, don't give me reference link of IBM Worklight Console & Administration kind of link. If anyone can provide me exact code or how to do that, I would be pleased.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the Event Source-based push notification tutorial and sample application? I do believe it does exactly that.

Learn about push notifications:

- Overview: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/
- Event source: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/#pnext_collapsible_1

Then scroll to the bottom of the page and select the desired environment and review the code and attached sample application.

Comment: thanks Idan. Let me look into it and get back to you

Comment: Idan I have seen the links. My concern is I am able to send push notifications and but right now i am not finding a way to send push notification to all subscribed/active users/devices.. Getting my point?

Means! When I run adapter my single message(notification) will be shown on all the devices

Comment: Not exactly: 
currently for usersubscrition here is the code
WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription('PushAdapter.PushEventSource', userID);

But right now, I don't have userID to get passed as parameter. I need to call an adapter and need to send to all the devices have my app
Make sense?

Comment: It will be displayed only on subscribed devices, not all devices.

Comment: Getting you. Idan 
But right now I am having an issue that when I KILL my app i couldn't receive push notifications?

Comment: I think you need to update your question with more than 2 lines of text; Explain exactly what you want and what you did thus far.